# broadcast is not triggering the on function to pass the data between controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, broadcast, watch

i am doing a add operation and on result of success i am routing to my main page.Both have respective controllers associated to.  I am broadcasting my success message and hope that the on function would recieve the call

```
carrierFactory.addCarrier(data).then(function(response){
$scope.CarrierDetails.reportSuccessMsg=response.data.reportSuccessMsg; 
$rootScope.$broadcast("SuccessMessage", response.data.reportSuccessMsg);
alert(response.data.reportSuccessMsg);
$location.path("/");
```

Then in the other controller which is assoicated with thr routed page , i am doing

```
$scope.$on("SuccessMessage", function(event, message) {
         $scope.reportSuccessMsg = message;
         alert("asdasD");
       });
```

Its not  working, so it shoudl be wrong, can you please suggest a better way in doing it. Thanks for help. I am very new to angular.

Comment: try $emit instead of $broadcast

Comment: the two view are not nested views. I believe emit is to share the date up. Anyways i will try and let u know the result. Thanks

Comment: $emti is not working. sorry  . thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should add listener to $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$on("SuccessMessage", function(event, message) {
     $scope.reportSuccessMsg = message;
     alert("asdasD");
});
```

Comment: Hi, yes i have tried with both rootScope and scope, but sorry, it is not working. i dont know what am i doing wrong

Comment: Can you create jsfild?